# How can I achieve predicate pushdown when using PyArrow + Parquet + Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow, gcsfuse

What I'm really trying to do is this (in Python):

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# Note the 'columns' predicate...
table = pq.read_table('gs://my_bucket/my_blob.parquet', columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

First, I don't think that gs:// is supported in PyArrow as of V3.0.0.
So I have to modify the code to use the fsspec interface: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-google-project')
with fs.open('my_bucket/my_blob.parquet', 'rb') as file:
    table = pq.read_table(file.read(), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Does this achieve predicate pushdown (I doubt it, because I'm already readying the whole file with file.read()), or is there a better way to get there?

Comment: Have you tried `table = pq.read_table(file, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])` (without the `read`). `read_table` supports "file like objects" as an argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-google-project')
table = pq.read_table('gs://my_bucket/my_blob.parquet', columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], filesystem=fs)
```

Comment: @user5406764 could you please tell us if this works for you

Comment: Yes this did indeed work.  I tested the load time with columns set to a single known column versus not specifying columns at all.  The load time was significantly faster with the single column.